# Is it possible to create .sqlite and .db file using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sqlite

I would like to know if we can create .sqlite and .db file programmatically from the webserver database using asp.net.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you absolutely can. Just use the [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org) wrapper and you should be able to create them as you need to.

Also, .db files could be any number of formats.